# Where do I return the quest item to join the Thieves Guild?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-ii-daggerfall

I started the quest to join the thieves guild in Daggerfall.
I did not read the note from the clothing pile, how do I know where to return the item to what city?

Answer (score 3):

You can check your journal, whether it updated with the new location from the note. If there is no new journal entry, you are out of luck, there is no other way to know the location besides reading the note.

You have one more in game option:
Travel through the current province you are in and look whether you can ask commoners about a certain person, this will be your contact. However, this is an exercise in futility and pure getting lucky unless you are in a small region.

Apart from that, your only choice is to reload the game and read the note.